# Magento 1.9 loads page twice on every page

Tags: magento-1.9

My site is built in Magento 1.9 and, starting from today, every page is loading twice. For instance I choose a page, it fully loads, then in 2 seconds makes another GET request (takes everything from cache) and stops. If I press the browser back button, then it makes the second GET again.

I didn't make any changes in JS or backend.

This is the browser back button pressed

[image]

Please help :)

**UPDATE!!!**

There was a script from surveyplanet that did this.

Comment: Please add your own answer and then mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was a script from surveyplanet that did this.